# PyCharm - Is community edition able to highlight php?

Tags: php, pycharm, highlight

i want to make pyCharm CE able to highlight php syntax. Here [PyCharm - Is community edition able to highlight css/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986720/pycharm-is-community-edition-able-to-highlight-css-javascript) is a solution for css, it worked. Have anyone such xml for php-syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Actually PHP syntax highlighting is just hidden - by the devs I assume ;)

`File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `File Types`

Above in `Recognized File Types` select PHP (syntax Highlighting Only)
Below in `Registered Patterns` press `+`, then enter `*.php`

In the dialog asking about the already registered wildcard, press `Reassign Wildcard`

Answer (score -1):

Why PyCharm? There is PHPStorm which is similar IDE as PyCharm but it is for PHP and it does highlight PHP syntax.

[image: like this]

**OR**

There is another editor which can highlight PHP syntax and code comletion as well
[here](http://hapedit.free.fr/php.php)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Because phpstorm have no CE version and some other reasons

Comment: In that case there is no way PyCharm can hightlight PHP syntax for you.

Comment: There are so many good free PHP Editors and IDEs. I suggest trying Netbeans PHP, Atom.io, and VS Code.

Comment: There is way, bcz I teach him highlight css from another topic solution. What I need is xml-file for php-syntax i guess it can be finded in some modules or may be someone maked it before or can advice how to make it by my own.

Sure I know about atom.io and other. Php not my only task and from my other task it is good to use one IDE for all projects.

Comment: @LeaAlter You might want to check if you are eligible for the discounted or free licences from JetBrains.

Comment: AFAIK no. I'm not student etc :)