# Is there a way to use CSS with PyCharm?

Tags: css, pycharm

I've been trying to use css in a pycharm project (I'm using flask, so that's why I'm using pycharm)-and I learned Pycharm isn't available in Community edition of Pycharm. When running the website, it leads to a bunch of problems-and the code I have doesn't have any problems. I've watched numerous tutorials on how to add CSS as a language, but none work. Is it possible to add CSS as a language to Pycharm Community edition? I'm using 2020.2.

Comment: `I learned Pycharm isn't available in Community edition of Pycharm` --> I think you have a typo/incorrect word here

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by enabling the plugins on the Settings/Preferences  Plugins page, see Managing Plugins for details See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/style-sheets.html#ws_css_completion) and [here](https://www.cuba-platform.com/discuss/t/how-to-turn-on-scss-highlighting-in-intellij-idea-ce/8104) where the completion for CSS, SCSS, Less, and Sass classes and ids are available in HTML files, in various types of templates (for example, in Angular or Vue.js), as well as in JSX code for Professional Edition. For Community Edition see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986720/pycharm-is-community-edition-able-to-highlight-css-javascript)

[image]

Comment: It says it is a professional feature at the top of the website-I was wondering if such a thing was possible in Community Edition.

Comment: You can get the Professional if you are a student.

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986720/pycharm-is-community-edition-able-to-highlight-css-javascript for  Community Edition