# Recognising Javascript Keywords in Pycharm Community Edition (let and const)

Tags: javascript, pycharm

I'm a beginner developer using PyCharm Community Edition (2019.2).
My project includes Javascript code for the frontend.
To date, I've been using the keyword `var` to declare my variables. The IDE shows `var` (and many other JS keywords) nicely in orange, which makes it easy to read my code.

I have recently learned that `let` and `const` (introduced in ES6) are more robust than `var`, and I understand the reasoning. But if I type `let` or `const` into my code, they don't turn orange. They stay white, which makes my code much less readable (to me, at least).

According to the PyCharm website, the Community Edition doesn't have any support for Javascript, so I'm surprised that my IDE is currently recognising `var` and others (`if`, `for`, `switch` etc).

Is there a way I can make the Pycharm Community Edition IDE recognise the keywords `let` and `const`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using another IDE for your front-end? One that is more suited for web development.

Here are two examples:
https://code.visualstudio.com/
https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

By the looks of it, your IDE supports JavaScript highlighting in the Professional Edition that is if you wish to upgrade.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20986966/19024729

A possible reason that generic programing terms such as `var`, `if` and `for` might be highlighting is that these terms will exist in other languages such as python which your IDE does highlight.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Adam! I'm not quite comfortable to switch IDE's at this stage of my project, but will certainly keep that in mind for future projects.
Also, your suggestion about it highlighting the ```var```, ```if```, ```for``` etc terms because they are generic seems very likely. Thanks!